# change an attribute of css

Tags: css

newbie question in css:

I have the following style defined:

```
TABLE.tabulardata th {
    font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #CAE8EA url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

I want to create an identical style but with different background color.

question: is it possible to parameterize the attribute. Background color in this case Or do i need to copy the same style again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
.myclass {
    font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}


TABLE.tabulardata th {
    background-color: #CAE8EA;
}
```

Then just add "myclass" to any element you want to share the attributes..

Comment: If you like this kind of thing, you might want to check out something like LESS - http://lesscss.org/
You can declare variables to hold styles, and call them whenever you want, to reuse / mix a bunch of styles together into new ones :)

Comment: thanks Jeriko for the quick answer. that helped me
I will look into the LESS option as well :)

Comment: LESS and HAML were great finds for me - they turn the most boring part of being a developer (IMO, at least) into a breeze. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible with pure css. what you can do is to create 3 styles with classes, one being common two both and then assign them to an element

```
.font { font-family: Linux Biolinum; }
.red { color:red; }
.blue { color:blue; }

<div class="font red">red</div>
<span class="font blue">blue</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
TABLE.tabulardata th, TABLE.tabulardataOther th {
    font: bold 11px "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #CAE8EA url(images/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}

TABLE.tabulardataOther th {
    background: #FFF url(images/other_header.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

This works because of CSS precedence. The first line sets `tabulardata` and `tabulardataOther` to the same style. Then the second line overrides just the background of tabulardataOther (leaving the other attributes the same).

Answer (score -1):

`background-color: red`

Comment: This question isn't about setting the background-color (he has already done that in the example in the question) it is about having a similar style between elements, with some differences. See Jeriko's answer.